# VLookup function in VBA - Return a department value based on name value

Tags: excel, vba, range, vlookup

I am looking to return a department value based off a name value. The name list is imported from a third party vendor, which randomizes the order each time, so I cannot set a department value to a specified cell. I have a range of data (dim rng) which has a name and column A and a department in column B. I would like the department associated with the name to be returned with the same on the new sheet. I have attached my code but am getting application defined or object-defined error and I am not sure why.

```
Sub find()

Dim namerng As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim depti As Integer
Dim dept As String

Set namerng = Range("A1:A250") 'range of names
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:B250") 'range of names in col A and dept in col B

    For depti = 3 To 250
     dept = "=IfError(Vlookup(namerng,rng,2,FALSE), "")"
     Range("B" & depti) = dept

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: Also, if you're adding a VBA reference into a string equation for Excel, you need to add the variables like `"=IfError(Vlookup(" & "namerng & "," & rng & ",2,FALSE), """")"` (Note the extra quotation marks to add them to the string. if you did `Debug.Print "=IfError(Vlookup(namerng,rng,2,FALSE), "")"`, the output would be `=IfError(Vlookup(namerng,rng,2,FALSE), ")`)

Comment: I am getting the error on the Range("B" & depti) = dept line

Comment: Adding that debug.print got the program to run, but no values are in column B for the department

Comment: I believe if you use `dept = "=IfError(Vlookup(" & namerng.Address & "," & rng.Address & ",2,FALSE), """")"`, it should run and insert the equation. However, I'm not convinced that this equation is what you want. Right now, there are circular references (everything's happening on the same sheet), and VLOOKUP only accepts one value for the first param, not a range of multiple cells.

Comment: Hmm yes, you are right.. It was working in the sheet because we could drag down the equation for each cell.

Comment: Maybe I need to take a new approach, if you have any ideas let me know!

Comment: I'm adding an answer now, that I think will work.

Comment: I believe this can all be done with a simple formula without VBA, if you could share more, a screenshot or a sample file/data, this would be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing some code to try and fulfill what you're wanting, so some of the below is an assumption.

```
Sub find()

    Dim namerng As Range 'List of Randomly Organized Names Only
    Dim Lookuprng As Range 'List of Names and Departments
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet

    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 'List of Randomly Organized Names Only
    Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2) 'List of Names and Departments

    'List of Names and Departments
    sh1.Activate
    Set Lookuprng = sh1.Range(Cells(1, 1), (Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)))

    'List of Randomly Organized Names Only  ******NEED TO SPECIFY WHERE THESE NAMES ARE COMING FROM, I used Sheet1
    sh2.Activate
    Set namerng = sh2.Range(Cells(1, 1), (Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)))

    'Put correct department with name
    namerng.Offset(0, 1) = Application.VLookup(namerng, Lookuprng, 2, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment! This worked very well for me, with the exception of a few tweaks just because, you are right, I picked a select part from my code to post so I had a few more things going along with it I had to account for. Thank you again!!

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer worked for you, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Just did! Sorry still new to this site haha

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of the issue and the problem you want to solve, I believe that the following code should work as needed.

```
Sub find()

Dim rng As Range
Dim depti As Integer
Dim dept As String

Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:B250") 'range of names in col A and dept in col B

    For depti = 3 To 250
     dept = "=IfError(Vlookup(A" & depti & ",'" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" & rng.Address & ",2,FALSE), """")"
     Range("B" & depti) = dept
    Next

End Sub
```

---

**Notes**

I eliminated the `namerng` variable, because we don't need it for the updated equation. Since VLookup only takes a single value as the first param, that value should be dependent on the value of the loop variable, same as the destination range is.

I also escaped the quotation marks, so that the function would be valid, and added in the sheet1.name, so that the range address will point to the correct sheet (with single quotation marks, in case the sheet name has a space in it).

A cautionary note: the way this is coded, the equation will be inserted on whichever sheet is the active one at the time of the code run. This means that if `Sheet1` is active, the departments will get overwritten with a circular-formula.

Comment: W-hit's answer looks like it will fill in the actually department values, while mine will fill in an excel equation which returns them. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55366184)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! This was getting the program to run, but would not pull the values from the second sheet that I needed. I think it was an issue on my end however, as my formulas in the sheet got messed up along the line, and anyone who sees this in the future can use this to help them out